Excel/Vba How to conditionally change the number format of ALL workbook cells with numbers in them, based on their number values?
I think this is a unique question which I need help with.
This code does NOT work but I hope there is a syntax that would work and I would also need to know where to put it.
In which event and at what level of code (Module or ThisWorkbook or Sheet)?
Or can this be done in Excel with some type of Conditional Formatting?
If Cells.Value = 0 Then
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0"
ElseIf Abs(Cells.Value) > 0 And Abs(Cells.Value) < 0.1 Then
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0.000"
ElseIf Abs(Cells.Value) >= 0.1 And Abs(Cells.Value) < 1 Then
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0.00"
ElseIf Abs(Cells.Value) >= 1 And Abs(Cells.Value) < 10 Then
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0.0"
ElseIf Abs(Cells.Value) >= 10 Then
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0"
End If

Thanks,
Dale
EDIT: Changes to accepted answer that handles numbers formatted as Currency and Percent:
Sub FormatCellWithNumber(ByVal cell As Range, ByRef FormattedCellsCount As Long)
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim NumFormat As String
    Value = cell.Value
    If VarType(Value) = vbCurrency Then  ' is currency
        Select Case Abs(Value)
            Case 0, Is >= 0.1: NumFormat = "$0.00"
            Case Is < 0.1: NumFormat = "$0.000"
        End Select
        FormattedCellsCount = FormattedCellsCount + 1
        cell.NumberFormat = NumFormat
    ElseIf VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then 'is a number
        If Is_formatted_as_percent(Range(cell.Address)) Then 'is a %
            Select Case Abs(Value)
                Case 0, Is >= 0.1: NumFormat = "0.0%"
                Case Is < 0.1: NumFormat = "0.00%"
            End Select
            FormattedCellsCount = FormattedCellsCount + 1
            cell.NumberFormat = NumFormat
        Else ' is a number
            Select Case Abs(Value)
                Case 0, Is >= 10: NumFormat = "0"
                Case Is < 0.1: NumFormat = "0.000"
                Case Is < 1: NumFormat = "0.00"
                Case Is < 10: NumFormat = "0.0"
            End Select
            FormattedCellsCount = FormattedCellsCount + 1
            cell.NumberFormat = NumFormat
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function Is_formatted_as_percent(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Is_formatted_as_percent = rng.NumberFormatLocal Like "*%*"
End Function

EDIT: My current issue with trying to use Conditional Formatting:


Cells.Value is an array. You can't call Abs on an array or compare an array to a scalar like that. Also... Cells.Value is likely an unnecessarily large array; maybe use UsedRange instead.

I was just trying to show how I wish I could do it.

Conditional formatting should work. How far did you get? Did anything block you?

Yes, I could not seem to find the syntax for all cells with numbers in them on the sheet to use for my range of say a =AND rule for between 1 and 10.

Assuming that your range is starting from cell A1, you can apply on it a conditional formatting with the rules =OR(A1=0;A1>=10) =AND(A1>0;A1<0.1) =AND(A1>=1;A1<1) =AND(A1>=1;A1<10). Of course if your range doesn't start from cell A1, you just swap the A1 with the actual starting cell address in the formula.

I tried what I thought you told me (after replacing ';'s with ','s) but had no luck. See my edit in my 1st topic post.

Format Cells with Numbers Conditionally in the Whole Workbook

This is a tool that will format the cells with numbers as required.
Before using it, create a copy of your file to test it.
Copy the complete code into a standard module e.g. Module1 of the workbook.
Run the code and determine if that is what you need.
You will have to save the file using either the .xlsm or .xlsb extension to keep the code in the workbook.
The code took about 25 seconds for 100k cells with numbers on a decade old machine. Share how long it took on your side.

Option Explicit

Sub FormatCellsWithNumbers()

    Const SECONDS_PER_100k As Long = 25 ' depends on the computer
    Const WARNING_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 100000
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference it by its name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.

    ' Count the number of cells with numbers.
    Dim CellsCount As Double: CellsCount = CellsWithNumbersCount(wb)
    If CellsCount > WARNING_CELLS_COUNT Then
        Dim msg As Long: msg = MsgBox("Found " & Format(CellsCount, "#,##0") _
            & " cells with numbers." & vbLf _
            & "Formatting that many cells will take about " _
            & Format(CellsCount / 100000 * SECONDS_PER_100k, "#,##0") _
            & " seconds." & vbLf & vbLf & "Do you want to continue?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Long Operation!")
        If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Start measuring the time passed.
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' increase efficiency
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, FormattedCellsCount As Long
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets and format cells containing numbers.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
            FormatCellWithNumber cell, FormattedCellsCount
        Next cell
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox Format(FormattedCellsCount, "#,##0") _
        & " cells with numbers formatted in " _
        & Format(Timer - t, "0") & " seconds.", vbInformation

End Sub

Function CellsWithNumbersCount(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Double
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, CellsCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
            If VarType(cell.Value) = vbDouble Then CellsCount = CellsCount + 1
        Next cell
    Next ws
    
    CellsWithNumbersCount = CellsCount
    
End Function

Sub FormatCellWithNumber(ByVal cell As Range, ByRef FormattedCellsCount As Long)
    
    Dim Value As Variant: Value = cell.Value
    
    Dim NumFormat As String
    
    If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        FormattedCellsCount = FormattedCellsCount + 1
        Select Case Abs(Value)
            Case 0, Is >= 10: NumFormat = "0"
            Case Is < 0.1: NumFormat = "0.000"
            Case Is < 1: NumFormat = "0.00"
            Case Is < 10: NumFormat = "0.0"
        End Select
        cell.NumberFormat = NumFormat
    'Else ' not a number
    End If

End Sub


Works like a charm unedited :) Took 8 seconds to do 6000 cells in my spreadsheet of interest.  I have 40 sheets now with more to come.  I will investigate why I am so much slower than you. I run W10Pro on a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz   3.19 GHz with 64GB ram. Worst case I just modify it to act on a worksheet when it is activated and have a button to 'Refresh Decimals' at any time I am working on a sheet.  Many thanks, powerful code, I have learned a LOT of new and very relevant syntax...

Aha, I had forgotten that, in those 8 seconds, I had a breakpoint and then an F5 to continue.  Actual time was 2.25 seconds so I am pretty close to your result.  Again, I am very impressed as this is and EXACT and COMPLETE answer to the Topic question :)

Thanks for the feedback. I had 5 sheets with 40 columns and 1000 rows, half numbers, half text, no formulas. I'm using MS365 64bit. Since you have a reasonable number of cells, you could out-comment the section "Count the number of cells with numbers." to improve efficiency.

I'm stuck at MSofficePro2010 32bit, that must be the final link in the speed difference issue.

That must be it, 32bit. I don't think the version has much to do with it. Luckily, VBA stayed almost the same. Maybe you should change the constants to something like 30 and 50000. Thanks again for your feedback.

FYI it seems that numbers which are formatted as Currency do not get reformatted and numbers that are formatted as % have to be handled with a different Case in your FormatCellWithNumber Sub (I have not found the syntax to do that elegantly yet, I am just currently pointing the case to each absolute cell that is formatted as % in its own Case and moving the decimal left two with a % at end of NumFormat).  If you have time can you edit your answer with elegant solutions to Currency and % cells :)
